# Where do I put cpanel backup files on www folder?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am using lamp to test a cpanel backup on ubuntu 16.04.
The website is a prestashop 1.4 bunch of folders.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEZfp.png)

As you can see in the image, there are many folders within folders. What do I put on www folder to show up on localhost?

I added the "public html" folder in it but it says 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have everything routed properly in php and you have your config setup accordingly, you should put all of it in your www folder.

Put all of your files in www, then start your webserver and try to open products.php (per example) in your browser.

Comment: I did and it shows nothing in localhost. Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: I have php installed. The original html file was showing fine (that it works) before I deleted it to put the site in. What do you mean is the server started? (Excuse me, I am not a programmer)

Comment: what url are attempting to direct to?

Comment: I am not trying to redirect anything. I am testing if prestashop works in my computer , since I want to do an upgrade to my site. (currently live) So that I can test and upgrade it before I upload it on the actual godaddy folder.

Comment: so in your browser you are not attempting to direct to a url in conjunction with localhost?

Comment: I put "localhost" there. Not a url.  I tried putting "localhost/public_html" but it still shows nothing.